# Ionic ng-repeat slow to load json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

```
 <div class="row categories-list">
  <div ng-repeat="img in gallery_data_imgur" class="col col-50">
    <a class="feed-category" ui-sref="app.imgur_img({imgId: img.id})">
      <pre-img ratio="_1_1" helper-class="square-image">
        <img class="category-image" ng-src="{{img.link}}" spinner-on-load>
      </pre-img>
      <div class="category-bg"></div>
      <span class="category-title">{{img.title}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

the code above loads an image gallery from a list of json objects.  The resulting ionic-view takes very long to render - most of the images are stuck in the 'loading' state.  I want to improve performance.  I know it is not the REST service that is sending the json objects to this view - because I see in the console that the response object is being returned very quickly - it is the construction of the view that is taking very long.

I've tried using collection-repeat but it does not seem to help performance.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.